# При загрузке любого сайта, в консоли выбивает ошибку `Mixed Content`

Tags: консоль, requests

При открытии любой страницы, абсолютно любой, в консоли регулярно получаю такую ошбику:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
'http://cdnsure.com/data/video/'.This request has been blocked;
the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

на месте 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' может быть адрес любого другого сайта - ошибка будет все-равно. Я так понял, что это происходит, когда пытаешься что-то оптравить и порт нужен защищенный, но я ничего отправляю, и уж тем более на все сайты.

Comment: Смешанный контент: Страница по адресу 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' была загружена через HTTPS, но был запрошен ненадёжный ресурс 'http://cdnsure.com/data/video/'. Этот запрос заблокирован; 
контент должен обслуживаться через HTTPS.

Comment: Страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask не содержит обращений к http://cdnsure.com/data/video/. Ищите, какие расширения браузера вставляют вам этот спам.

Comment: @KAGGDesign , да, пожалуй только удаление расширений и помогло. Не стал разбираться, какое именно консоль забивало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае это давало расширение Ummy Video Downloader

Comment: да-да, у меня тоже был загрузчик видео с Ютуба. Может, даже именно такой.